# Join with Mysql CONCAT() function

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

```
          SELECT orders.*, user.name, user.CONCAT(adress,city) as adress
          FROM  orders, user 
          WHERE user.id = orders.user_id 
          ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```

> I want to retrieve address, city, name from user table and all from orders table. I want to combine address and city as an address. But It gives an error.what is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT orders.*, user.name, CONCAT(user.adress," ",user.city) as adress
      FROM  orders, user 
      WHERE user.id = orders.user_id 
      ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```